# crond appears to be working, but doesn't write to /var/spool/mail/root

Tags: centos, cron

I'm using `cron` to schedule tasks and mail their output to me on several preexsiting CentOS 7 systems.

On some systems, everything cron mails gets written to `/var/spool/mail/root`, which is what I expect.

On others, however, the file is very old and does not get updated with the output of new jobs - even though it is being accessed on time, according to `ls` and `stat`.

I'm not sure what's wrong or how to fix it - I've had trouble finding documentation on cron mailing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which user is running your cron jobs? Is there an entry (near the top of the crontab file) starting `MAIL=`? Do any jobs actually produce output/errors? (No output = no email)

Comment: The user is root, there is no `MAIL=` entry (but mail works), and the jobs do produce output

Comment: `/var/mail` perhaps?

Comment: both `var/mail` and `var/spool/mail` have the same file (`root`), which is accessed but not updated

Comment: Please check `grep '^root' /etc/aliases`. Any output?

Comment: No, it comes out empty

Comment: What about `ls -l /usr/*bin/sendmail` - what executable does it point to?

Comment: It links to '/etc/alternatives/mta', on both working and non working servers

Comment: Where does that point? Can you follow down the chains please

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there's another link. It point to `/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix`.

Comment: Run `echo boo | mail -v root` to send a simple email (a) it should print several lines of output. Please add those to your question (formatted), (b) did the message land in `/var/spool/mail/root`?

Comment: It complains about `cat`: 
`cat: invalid option -- 'S'`. Now I'm really confused...

Comment: I feel like we're heading down a rabbit hole... `mail` shouldn't be calling `cat`. But it does seem like the mail subsystem is broken in some way. Do you have an IT Administrator person/team who would look at this for you? It's probably too detailed now for this discussion here

Comment: You've helped me identify the problem - I think I can make further attempts from here. Thank you so much for your time and patience.